# Calculating the Time for a Skier to Traverse a Snowy Field with Visited and Unvisited Path Segments

Tags: algorithm, sum

The skier is skiing in a snowy field. His movements can be described by sequences of "S", "N", "W", "E" symbols (corresponding to a 10-meter movement south, north, west, or east).

It is known that if he moves along a previously unvisited path segment (i.e. this path segment is visited for the first time), the time for such a movement is 5 seconds. If he slides along a path segment that was visited before (i.e. this path segment was already passed), it takes 1 second.

Find the time it takes for the skier to complete the entire path.

The first line contains an integer t - the number of queries in the input. Each query set is presented as a single line of symbols 'S', 'N', 'W', 'E'.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    public class Position
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var requestCount = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            var results = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < requestCount; i++)
            {
                var movments = Console.ReadLine()
                                      .ToCharArray()
                                      .ToList();

                results.Add(GetMovmentPrice(movments));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
        }

        static int GetMovmentPrice(List<char> movments)
        {
            var postion = new Position { X = 0, Y = 0 };
            var knownPositions = new Dictionary<Position, bool>();
            knownPositions.Add(new Position { X = postion.X, Y = postion.Y }, true);

            var price = 0;

            foreach (var movment in movments)
            {
                switch (movment)
                {
                    case 'N':
                        postion.Y++;
                        break;
                    case 'S':
                        postion.Y--;
                        break;
                    case 'W':
                        postion.X--;
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        postion.X++;
                        break;
                }

                bool founded = false;

                foreach (var key in knownPositions.Keys)
                {
                    if (key.X == postion.X && key.Y == postion.Y)
                    {
                        price += 1;
                        founded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (founded)
                    continue;

                price += 5;
                knownPositions.Add(new Position { X = postion.X, Y = postion.Y }, true);

            }
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting wrong anwser for following input:

```
5
S
SENNWWEENWESNEEWSWNSNNENSNWSNWSSNNNWSWNNNWNENESNNNSEEEWEWEEWNEWNWSSWENSWSSNNE
EWEENWWWNENENNSSEEWENNWSSWSNSENENWWEEENESNSSESSSEWEESNESSESSSNENSNWNWWWESWEEWEESSSES
SWNEWNESWWSWENENSSNWEWNWNNWNWWEWEWNNSWNEESNSNWSSENWSWSWSNESSSEWESSESWWENWWSWNSWWNEWSNNWE
WNWNSSNWESENEEWSEENENSWWWESSNNESENNENNNWNEWWSEWESSSNSWSENWEESSEESESNWSWSEEWESNSSNS
```

My answer:

```
5
249
280
276
246
```

Correct answer:

```
5
265
304
300
278
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method in JavaScript:

```js
function g(str) {
  const seen = new Set();
  let total = 0;
  let x = 0;
  let y = 0;
  let u;
  
  for (const direction of str) {
    u = String([x, y]);
    
    switch(direction) {
      case 'N':
        y += 1;
        break;
      case 'S':
        y -= 1;
        break;
      case 'E':
        x += 1;
        break;
      default:
        x -= 1;
        break;
    }
    
    const segment = [u, String([x, y])].sort();
    const key = String(segment);

    total += seen.has(key) ? 1 : 5;
    
    seen.add(key);
  }
  
  return total;
}

function f(A) {
  return A.map(g).join('\n');
}

var A = [
  'S',
  'SENNWWEENWESNEEWSWNSNNENSNWSNWSSNNNWSWNNNWNENESNNNSEEEWEWEEWNEWNWSSWENSWSSNNE',
  'EWEENWWWNENENNSSEEWENNWSSWSNSENENWWEEENESNSSESSSEWEESNESSESSSNENSNWNWWWESWEEWEESSSES',
  'SWNEWNESWWSWENENSSNWEWNWNNWNWWEWEWNNSWNEESNSNWSSENWSWSWSNESSSEWESSESWWENWWSWNSWWNEWSNNWE',
  'WNWNSSNWESENEEWSEENENSWWWESSNNESENNENNNWNEWWSEWESSSNSWSENWEESSEESESNWSWSEEWESNSSNS'
]

console.log(f(A));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you are keeping track of visited *positions*, but the question requires you to keep track of visited *path segments*

To identify a path segment, you need a position and direction.  Note that each segment is adjacent to *two* positions, so you have to be careful to ensure that each unique segment has only one representation.  Something like this works:

```
public class Segment
{
    // Western-most X coordinate of the segment
    public int X { get; set; }
    // Southern-most Y coordinate of the segment
    public int Y { get; set; }
    // Direction of the path segment from (X,Y):
    // true for N, false for E
    public bool dirNnotE {get; set;}
}
```